# check incoming type of data with socket.recv

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I need my program to know if the message from the client is a number, so int or float, or a string.

Until now, my program look like this:

```
    def handle_client_text(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    
    connected = True
    while connected:
            msg_lenght = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg_lenght:
                msg_lenght = int(msg_lenght)
                msg = conn.recv(msg_lenght).decode(FORMAT)
                if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                    connected = False
                    conn.close()
                    print ("disconnecting")
                print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            
        sleep(0.001)
    
def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client_text, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")
```

I need that it can receive numbers other than strings, and that it acts in a different way if its a number or a string.

Every variable that isn't defined here is defined in another part of the code.

Comment: It depends on how complex you need, but you could preface each message with some metadata that says what type the data coming in is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data that are coming via socket is in byte form, and it becomes a string when you `decode()` it and becomes int or float if you convert it with `int()` or `float()` respectively.

Hence, if you want to have different logic based on its datatype, You should either check for all digits/dots or alphanumeric characters to classify between numeric and string datatypes. or, If you may have to treat `"12"` as string instead of int, send data type as meta data from client.